# Javascript - window.location.assign not working

Tags: javascript, url, qr-code

I've a project where I scan a QR code, and it will then automatically print out information based on which code was scanned.

I have the scanner, and a printer. Each QR code is to correspond to a URL. I can get the scanner to fill an input field, and I can get an alert to show the information that was scanned. However, whenever I try to assign the URL it simply appends the information to the current URL, instead of replacing it.

I need it to replace the current URL. Does anyone know why it is doing this, and how to fix it?

```
<html>
<head><title>QR Printing</title></head>

<body onload="document.myform.mytextfield.focus();">

<form name="myform">
    <input type="text" name="mytextfield" onchange="checkForm()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

function checkForm() { 
    var field1 = document.forms['myform'].elements['mytextfield'].value; 
    alert(field1);
    window.location.assign(field1);
}    

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use `<input autofocus />` instead of `<body onload="something very long">`

Comment: Do you want to **redirect** the user to the new address or only to **replace the text** in the url-bar in the browser?

Comment: @Al.G. - I want to redirect based upon the URL that is supplied by the scanned QR code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the form is submitting. Cancel it.

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="return false">
```

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
window.location = field1;
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it still simply adds the information to the end of the URL

Comment: it shouldn't it should send you to the new url

Comment: Here's the page I'm playing with. Just type something and hit enter (equates to the same thing as scanning a code) - http://aspecteleven.com/qr_print.html

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the solutions worked for me in chrome browser. 
I have resolved this using:

```
setTimeout(function () { document.location.href = YourUrlLink }, 500);
```

Hope this helps who are seeking a solution for chrome browser issue.

Answer (score 0):

add return false; after window.location.assign(field1);

```
 <html>
<head><title>QR Printing</title></head>

<body onload="document.myform.mytextfield.focus();">

<form name="myform">
    <input type="text" name="mytextfield" onchange="checkForm()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

function checkForm() { 
    var field1 = document.forms['myform'].elements['mytextfield'].value; 
    alert(field1);
    window.location.assign(field1);
    return false;
}    

</script>

</body>
</html>
```