# window.location.assign() doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I am using this line of code:

```
window.location.assign("<website name>")
```

This does not work for me. It just refreshes the page and does not go to the actual page I am requesting. I can go to the page by typing in the link, but the redirect does not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post the URL string you are passing as a parameter? My first guess would be you are not prefixing it with 'www' .

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be trying to do this in response to user activity on a `form` element, would you? The `form` submission will override your attempt to reassign the `location`, see [Javascript - window.location.assign not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936947/javascript-window-location-assign-not-working).

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that you are skipping the protocol:

Try this:

```
window.location.assign('http://www.websitename.com');
```

Without specifying `http` **or** `https` it won't work.

Note that you can actually skip the `assign` part and just do:

```
window.location = 'http://www.websitename.com';
```

But again it won't work without a protocol specified.

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPXbYz)

And example here:

```js
window.location = 'http://example.com';
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. It just refreshed the page again.

Comment: without seeing your `url` I can't help more. I assure you that either of the above will work and I pasted an example codepen to show.